# kepler.gl state doesnt exist. You might forget to mount keplerGlReducer in your root reducer

Tags: reactjs, kepler.gl

I try to integrate `kepler.gl` into [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).

I Mount kepler.gl reducer in the app reducer like this

```
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    keplerGl: keplerGlReducer,  // mount kepler.gl reducer
    global: globalReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });

  // Wrap the root reducer and return a new root reducer with router state
  const mergeWithRouterState = connectRouter(history);
  return mergeWithRouterState(rootReducer);
}
```

and in the create store part, I have

```
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    taskMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
  ];

  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  );
```

When I run the app, I get red text from console complaining

> kepler.gl state doesnt exist. You might forget to mount
>   keplerGlReducer in your root reducer.If it is not mounted as
>   state.keplerGl by default, you need to provide getState as a prop

and the map is not displayed in the page, but I can see the keplerGl state from redux DevTools like this.

[image]

Could you suggest how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and it works.

I think that you have forgotten add `enhanceReduxMiddleware`;

I hope this help you.

reducer.js

```
// KEPLER.GL
import keplerGlReducer from "kepler.gl/reducers";

/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
const createReducer = injectedReducers => {
    return combineReducers({
        global: globalReducer,
        language: languageProviderReducer,
        keplerGl: keplerGlReducer,
        ...injectedReducers,
    });
};

export default createReducer;
```

configureStore.js

```
import { enhanceReduxMiddleware } from 'kepler.gl/middleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {

    // Create the store with two middlewares
    // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
    // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
    const middlewares = enhanceReduxMiddleware([thunk]);

    const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

    const store = createStore(
        createReducer(),
        initialState,
        composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
    );
    return store;
};
```